# php to find the content of a div

Tags: php, html

I want to execute some code if a div has an image inside, but can't correctly complete the first line
(I think other lines are ok):

```
$page = index.php; // should be my homepage
$content = $page->find('div[id=sky]', 0)->innertext;
if($content == '<img src="img/water.png">'){
//do something
}
```

Comment: are you trying to use jQuery in PHP?

Comment: whatever library are you using?

Comment: $page comes from server. the code is a part of php form validation

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to use the [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), as it looks like, you need to initialize it.

**UPDATE:** You of course need to download ([Download Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/simplehtmldom/1.5/)), unpack, upload it to your server and the finally include it to have access to those functions.

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$page = file_get_html('http://www.mydomain.com/index.php');
```

Comment: @ MiDo i replaced the first line with `$page = file_get_html('localhost/index.php');` and got error on that line

Comment: @Alegro, first of all you must download [`simple_html_dom.php`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/latest/download?source=files) then `include('simple_html_dom.php');`

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_get_html() in C:\wamp\www\memb_area\register.php on line 3